# Garage door won't close in cold weather

Tags: doors, garage, garage-door-opener

My garage door works perfectly when it's above 45 degrees.  As it gets colder I have to hold the wall mounted master garage door opener/closer in to have the garage door close.  It opens fine. I've lubed the rails and rollers, chain, chain sprocket, pretty much everything.  This is the second winter in a row where it has not been able to close with one hit of the remote or the wall mounted switch. The unit is a Sears Craftsman 1/2 hp, chain, mfg in 2010.

Comment: Does it close smoothly when you disconnect the opener and run it by hand in the cold?

Comment: I just went outside and ran the door up and down by hand a couple of times. There are no constrictions and it glides up and down without much effort.